# Communication from inner directive with main directive - calling a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two directives. First is using (including) second.

This is my child directive:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('radioType', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        question: '=',
        onAnswer: '&'
      },
      template: [
        '<div>{{vm.question.text}}<br/>',
        '<div>',
        '<button ng-repeat="a in vm.question.answers track by $index" ng-click="onSelected(a)">{{a.text}}</button>',
        '</div>',
        '<button ng-click="myFunction()">Radio</button>',
        '</div>'
      ].join(''),
      controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.myFunction = function() {
          console.log("hello from radio controller");
          $scope.vm.onAnswer();
        };
        $scope.onSelected = function(question) {
          $scope.vm.question.answer = question.text;
          console.log(question);
        };
      }],
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      bindToController: true
    };
  });
```

and this is my main directive:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('question', function($compile) {
  var combo = '<div>COMBO - {{vm.content.text}}</div>';
  var radio = [
    '<radio-type question="vm.content" onAnswer="vm.onAnswer()"></radio-type>'
  ].join('');
  var input = [
    '<input-type question="vm.content"></input-type>',
  ].join('');

  var getTemplate = function(contentType) {
    var template = '';

    switch (contentType) {
      case 'combo':
        template = combo;
        break;
      case 'radio':
        template = radio;
        break;
      case 'input':
        template = input;
        break;
    }

    return template;
  }

  var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {

    scope.$watch('vm.content', function() {
      element.html(getTemplate(scope.vm.content.type))
      $compile(element.contents())(scope);

    });
  }

  return {
    restrict: "E",
    link: linker,
    scope: {
      content: '='
    },
    controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.onAnswer = function() {
        console.log("answer");
      };
    }],
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true
  };
})
```

Inside child directive I have buttons, when someone clicks on one of them I'd like to call function from main directive.
I've included `onAnswer: '&'` in my child directive, and I'm assigning function inside main directory template, but I can get this working.

Here is Plunker showing my problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/iWU4L3IJLHtADHBl2dIh?p=preview

Any other advice are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 errors on `scripts.js`.

On line 6 your attribute should not be camelCase:

```
'<radio-type question="vm.content" on-answer="vm.onAnswer()"></radio-type>'
```

and on line 46 your function should be inside object `vm`:

```
$scope.vm.onAnswer = function() {
```

Check this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/8O7BRjfE3ZWFLrvMkbXB?p=preview

Comment: Thank You so much for help. I'm new to Angular and I didn't knew I must declare functions as `$scope.vm`. Can I declare them normally, without `vm`? Is it because of `bindToController`?

Comment: I just updated my answer without the `vm`. Works perfectly

Comment: Thank You again. But I'd like to leave `controllerAs` (trying to follow John Papa's styleguide) and declare functions in scope, without extra `vm` in middle. Is this even possible?